# Not able to create the (correct) bibliography using bibtex and natbib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am not able to add the citation from the current `references.bib` file into my main tex file. The output i am getting are the references in the old `references.bib` file, which i have deleted.

final.tex

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\setcitestyle{numbers}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes default name Bibliography to References
\bibliography{References/references} % references.bib file located in References folder 
\end{document}
```

references.bib file contents

```
@article{aps:1,
  title={An introduction to social network data analytics},
  author={Aggarwal, Charu C},
  journal={Social network data analytics},
  pages={1--15},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{aps:2,
  title={A survey of clustering algorithms for big data: Taxonomy and empirical analysis},
  author={Fahad, Adil and Alshatri, Najlaa and Tari, Zahir and Alamri, Abdullah and Khalil, Ibrahim and Zomaya, Albert Y and Foufou, Sebti and Bouras, Abdelaziz},
  journal={IEEE transactions on emerging topics in computing},
  volume={2},
  number={3},
  pages={267--279},
  year={2014},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: Why does `final.tex` contain four [4!] `\bibliographystyle` instructions? Which one of them is supposed to be the one you wish to you? Separately, after changing the argument of `\bibliography`, did you perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more? Please tell us exactly what you're doing.

Comment: i am using texmaker and i did "Quick Build" in it. i removed three \bibliographystyle.

Comment: Incidentally, the entry type and some of the fields for the entry with key `aps:1` are almost certainly quite wrong. According to information available at http://www.springer.com/de/book/9781441984616, the entry type should most definitely not be `@article`. Instead, the entry type should probably be `@incollection`, the `journal` field should be renamed `booktitle`, and the fields `editor={Aggarwal, Charu C},` and `chapter=1,` should be added. I haven't checked the information for the second entry you've listed, but it may have to be modified as well.

Comment: Please advise whether or not you performed a full recompile cycle after modifying the argument of `\bibliography`. (I don't know what "Quick Build" entails.) Also, which one of the four `\bibliographystyle` instructions should remain?

Comment: i have used google scholar to get both. and modified the key

Comment: i have modified the question and removed the additional styles.

Comment: Please provide code that actually produces the issue you're looking to fix. The code you've posted so far contains no `\cite` instructions; hence, it won't create a bibliography either. For what it's worth, I have been so far unable to reproduce the issue you've described in your posting. This strongly suggests that there's something important about your computing setup that you haven't revealed so far, and which is the true cause of the issue. Don't expect anyone to be able to simply "guess" the cause of the problem.

Comment: Incidentally, bibliographic information obtained from Google Scholar should always be treated as potentially highly suspect. *You* are responsible for the contents of your thesis -- *including* what's listed in the bibliography. For sure, the excuse that "I obtained the bib entries from Google Scholar" will likely not fly with your thesis committee and your university.

Comment: your document has no `\cite` commands so naturally it will have an empty bibliography.

Answer (score -1):

You have not cited any of the references, therefore nothing appears.

Simply add a citation and you will get the result.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{aps:1}
\setcitestyle{numbers}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes default name Bibliography to References
\bibliography{References/references} % references.bib file located in References folder
\end{document}
```